# How to Fix: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest was not found:package: 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Tags: windows, .net-core, dependencies

We are new to .Net Core and are trying to deploy our first application that uses it.  We are deploying to a Windows server which has .NET Core Windows Server Hosting Module (2.2.0), the .NET Core Runtime (2.2.0) and I even installed the SDK (2.2.103) to see if that could solve the problem, which it did not.

Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (accesslog.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'System.Data.SqlClient', version: '4.5.1'
    path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Data.SqlClient.dll'

So, here is my issue...the above error is being generated when we try to run a .NET Core application via the "dotnet filename.dll" method.  We "publish" the application to generate all needed dependencies, or so I thought.  The publish (and thus application) folder contain "A" version of this file (System.Data.SQlClient.dll), but apparently not the right one (version in publish path shows 4.6.26606.5), but  yet that is the one being generated by Visual Studio.

Oddly, we also have an ASP.NET application on this same server which runs fine and references the same file.

Any help, guidance, troubleshooting steps, etc would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am having the exact same issue :(

Comment: Me having the same issue System Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (megfarmerapi.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents', version: '4.6.0'
    path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll'

Comment: Anyone able to solve this? Seeing the same issue...